# stamps.com php SOAP integration. (404) not found error?

Tags: php, soap, http-status-code-404, stamps.com

I am trying to Authenticate a user using stamps.com API and php and I am getting the following error:

```
:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] Server was unable to process request. ---> The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
//Authenticate Stamps.com SOAP API
 $IntegrationID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
 $Username = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
 $Password = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
 $wsdl =  "https://swsim.testing.stamps.com/swsim/swsimv50.asmx?wsdl";

 //Authenticate User
 $authData = array(
    "Credentials"  => array(
        "IntegrationID"  => $IntegrationID,
        "Username"       => $Username,
        "Password"       => $Password
                            )
    );

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);
$auth = $client->AuthenticateUser($authData);
$AuthenticatorToken = $auth->Authenticator;
```

I cant seem to find a solution to this anywhere, any ideas what might be causing the error?

Answer (score 1):

The Stamps.com API requires that you register as a developer and provide your IP address so that they can add it to the API whitelist before you can use the API.

If you haven't yet registered for a developer account with Stamps.com you can do so here: http://developer.stamps.com/developer/register/

Comment: I'm not sure this would explain a 404 error, though it is possible. A 403 forbidden error would make more sense.

Comment: Agreed, @Jonathan727, a 403 would make more sense. I've received 404 because my IP wasn't on the whitelist (web hosting configuration had SOAP requests happening from a different IP than that of the web server).